# Move div to top for small screens

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I have a layout which should look a bit different for pc screens and smartphones.

```
Layout 1:
|1 | 2      |
|3 | 4  |5  |
|6 | 7  |8  |

Layout 2:
|4|
|1|
|2|
|3|
|5|
|6|
|7|
|8|
```

You can see, that within Layout 2 the div (or in this sample, article) should move to the top, with the other divs below.

How can this be done, when I like to use plain HTML + CSS for this, no JS/jQuery.... !?

Fiddle is right here: https://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/vsn8nod7/
The green div is the one, that should sit on top in mobile layout, as it contains the description text of the page, the others divs contain just images.

Comment: You are required to supply the minimal code and markup here that shows the problem, not some third-party site that may go away tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox can do that:

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ezNgpj)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.child {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: pink;
  flex: 0 0 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  order: 1;
}
.wider {
  flex: 0 0 66.66%;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .child {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
  .topper {
    order: 0;
    background: orange;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child wider">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child topper">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
  <div class="child">8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is using the bootstrap grid, as it makes working with grids so much easier.

If you do not want to use bootstrap, you can use media queries in your css to hide or show a div depending on the screen size:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
    #div4a {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 399px) {
    #div4b {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: It's not the solution I was hoping for, but, in this case, it works for me. :-)Thx! Let's just wait and see if there is another possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same code in your fiddle with a small change

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #content {
        width: auto;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        margin: 20px 0;
    } 
    article#pic4 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        height: auto;
    }
   article#pic1{
        margin-top: 18px;

}

}
```